# Revert NSLayoutConstraint of UIView after changing the constraint

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

> Currently, I am expanding a custom view inside a scrollview to
> fullscreen after the user taps on it. But I want the View to come back
> to the original position once the user taps on it again. Note:- I have
> set the original custom view position inside the scrollview on Xib
> visually, I haven't added the code programmatically to add views in
> scroll view.

Here is my code to expand:-

```
 let frameAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.6, dampingRatio: 1) {
                self.playerDescriptionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                self.playerDescriptionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                self.playerDescriptionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                self.playerDescriptionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }
frameAnimator.startAnimation()
```

So, how can I set the constraint back to the original position while minimizing the view, because I have not set the view constraint programmatically?

Comment: The usual way to “zoom” a view is with a custom transition animation to a presented view. Like Apple’s Photos app when you tap a thumbnail.

Comment: @matt I want to make the animation more like the new card style whenever the user taps on any card on Appstore's Today Tab, then you see that the card zooms out from that location.

Comment: you can use self.transform for expand, and when you can return to initial value setup transform to .identity instead using constraint for your animation

Comment: Yes and I am telling you what that animation is. To do like Apple does, you need to know what Apple does. As I said, it’s a full view controller presentation with custom transition animation.